# Zabbix who.is domain check script, customizing grep values

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, zabbix

**Hello **fellas,

I'm having trouble with my script that connect to who.is website and check if domain is still viable or not. Everything seems to work fine if values that are represented on who.is are typed with slashes 2022/05/05.
Problem happens if date is done with dots 2022.05.05 that gives me wrong format.

I'm using script that Kulpin74 made, link to source code:
https://github.com/kulpin74/zabbix-ssl/blob/master/externalscripts/whois_expire.sh

I can see it does grep date, but can i postprocess it later:
if(grep *.* replace /) and continue doing script? I think that would solve my problem but couldn't find solution on website.

Thank you for any help :)

Was looking on internet to change . with / but couldn't find solution.
Was trying to find other scripts that maybe someone did solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which domain is responding with dot separator within date, it would be great if you can provide that domain so the case is identified.

According to the issue description, I have made an edit with a pull-request into main repo

Link to merge request: https://github.com/kulpin74/zabbix-ssl/pull/16

Link to file with edit: https://github.com/kulpin74/zabbix-ssl/blob/1e0f49e312e882f9f51073838ffcc92d3d57b70d/externalscripts/whois_expire.sh

Thanks